# slide image from left to right and reverse back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to slide image from left to right and after a set point it should again slide in reverse direction. This is my code somehow its not working as i am going wrong somewhere in the if statement.

```js
(function($) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    //cache a reference to the banner  
    var banner = $("#banner");
    // set initial banner background position  
    banner.css('backgroundPosition', x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');
    // scroll up background position every 90 milliseconds  
    window.setInterval(function() {
        banner.css("backgroundPosition", x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');
        x++;
        //x--;  
        //if you need to scroll image horizontally -  
        // uncomment x and comment y  
    }, 90);
    if ($(banner.offset().left > 40) {
        banner.css("backgroundPosition", "0px 0px ");
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
div#banner {
  width: 960px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/img/companypageadfallback-leaderboard-2.png?v=59b591051ad7) no-repeat 0 0;
}
div#banner p {
  font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 120px;
  width: 305px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Comment: The `if` is outside the timer callback, so only runs once.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are using a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) instead of a DOM ready handler. This code will only work if placed after the elements it references.

Use this shortcut for DOM ready that also provides a locally scoped `$`

```
jQuery(function ($) {...});
```

You also have a missing closing paren (or really a redundant `$(` as it is already a jQuery object):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/g0gn4osy/7/

You also need to have a delta value that changes the direction when you hit a bound value. I sped up your timing to show this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var delta = 1;
    var y = 0;
    //cache a reference to the banner  
    var $banner = $("#banner");

    // set initial banner background position  
    $banner.css('background-position', '0px' + ' ' + y + 'px');

    // scroll up background position every 90 milliseconds  
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var position = parseInt($banner.css('background-position'));
        if (position >= 40 || position < 0) {
            delta = -delta;
        }
        position += delta;
        $banner.css("background-position", position + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');
    }, 10);

});
```

### Notes:

- You also had `backgroundPosition` instead of `background-position` for the CSS property. I prefer to use the values that match the css properties (personal choice only for maintenance).
- To avoid the redundant `$()` issue, I recommend you prefix jQuery variables with `$`. e.g. `$banner` in this case. Then it becomes obvious you are dealing with a jQuery object.
- I tend to use the current position of an element, rather than keep a global var running. This allows for external influences to change the position and still work. Have removed `x` and just use position.

Comment: As you wish :) With removing `x` variable it does make sense in this code.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired and modelled on **Gone Coding's** answer.

I have expanded his example to take into account the **image width** and the **view pane** `DIV` width.

It now scrolls to image end and then back. You never scroll off the canvas or past a visible part of the image. It doesn't jerk or rock, just switches direction.

With awareness of the viewing box width you can easily adjust the width of `div#banner` to fit the display space and the code adjusts. Just remember to set the background image width `imgW` var.

**I have also added:**

1. **Visual indicator** for testing with a current position and scroll direction. (With `-1` is scrolling left, `+1` is scrolling right),
2. **Image start position** in `px`. (A minus number or Zero. With `0` is start image at left, Minus number is start image part way through i.e image pre-scrolled left)
3. **Image start vertical position** in `px` (to vertically pull image up/down. Useful if view pane height shorter than image height and you want to tweak what is seen)

**Things to do:**

1. Change image URL (`background: url(IMAGENAMEHERE) no-repeat 0 0;`)
2. Insert image width (`var imgW = #PIXELWIDTH#;`)
3. Play with WIDTH: and HEIGHT: of view pane (`div#banner`)

Enjoy.

## Fiddle

Have a play http://jsfiddle.net/Lm5yk46h/

Image credit Mark Higgins | Dreamstime.com [Image source for purchase](https://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-image-newcastle-beach-image28506086)

## Javascript

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var delta = 1;
    var imgW = 3000;//width of image px
    var imgY = 0;//to shift image view vertically px (Minus or zero)

    //cache ref to #banner  
    var $banner = $("#banner");
    var viewpaneW = $banner.width();
    var endpos = (imgW - viewpaneW);
    var startpos = 0;//0 or negative number

    // set initial banner background position
    $banner.css('background-position', startpos + 'px' + ' ' + imgY + 'px');

    // scroll background position every 20ms
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var position = parseInt($banner.css('background-position'));
        // minus is left, plus is right
        if (position >= 0 ) delta = -delta;//go left
        if (position < (-1*endpos)) delta = (-1*delta);//go right
        position += delta;//increment posn
        $banner.css("background-position", position + 'px' + ' ' + imgY + 'px');
        $("#indicator").text('Posn:' + position + '  | direction: ' + delta);
    }, 20);
});
```

## CSS

```
div#canvas {
    background-color: #999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin:0;padding:10px;
}
div#banner {
    width: 460px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: url(https://digido.net/eg/newcastle-beach-3000x300.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
div#banner p {
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 310px;
    width: 99%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div id="banner">
        <p id="indicator">Hit run</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some unknown reason I cannot insert my code blocks (although correctly indented). ??? Ideas anyone?

Comment: Must have been an invisible *bad* character, after 40mins I managed to get code blocks loaded. Hope someone gets benefit of this effort ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `if` condition inside the `setInterval`. And check the syntax error. The `if` doesn't have a closing `}`:

```
// scroll up background position every 90 milliseconds  
window.setInterval(function() {
  banner.css("backgroundPosition", x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');
  x++;
  //x--;  

  if (banner.offset().left > 40) {
      banner.css("backgroundPosition", "0px 0px ");
  }

}, 90);
```

Comment: This does not slide back again when the limits are reached. The original code needs enhancing to support that.

Answer (score 0):

Your "if" should be like this:

```
if ($(banner).offset().left > 40) {
    banner.css("backgroundPosition", "0px 0px ");

  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wc4b2g97/

Comment: This does not "slide" back again when it hits 40px as requested. Actually your JSFiddle *never* stops sliding to the right.

Answer (score -1):

your if should be inserted inside your setInterval handler, so it would get evaluated every 90 milliseconds (thank you for correcting me).

Actually, your if is evaluted only the first time, when your javascript file is parse.

Add it into your setInterval and it should work as expected

Comment: 90 "millisconds" and you missed the other problems.. update: You still missed the other problems